# Getting NullReferenceException and object reference not set to an instance of an object when trying to get the role claim from the header

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0

im trying to get the role claim and verify the it before adding a new user

```
var role = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Role).Value;
```

i have already registered service in programs.cs

```
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

and initialized well

```
  private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public DBService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: no please ...i already looked through

Comment: Then check first if your Claims contain a role claim. If not FindFirst will return null and a call to `.Value` will fail the way you say.

Comment: @Ralf yes i have a role claim as part of my claims

Comment: @stepofori So you have debugged your code and seen that the Claims contain the Roles claim but you have not seen where the NullRefrenceException occurs while doing that?

Comment: [Tutorial: Learn to debug C# code using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger).

Comment: @Ralf 
                    var claims = new[] {
                        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, _configuration["JwtConfig:Subject"]),
                        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()),
                        new Claim("Email", user.Email.ToString()),
                        new Claim("Password", user.Password.ToString()),
                        new Claim("Role", role.ToString()),

Comment: @stepofori there are presumably a gazillion things happening between the code you show in this comment that creates the claims and reaching the code you show in your question that needs the claim. You need to find out if it reaches the code in question. And the tool checking it is debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found the answer... this line was looking for a claimtype Role

```
var role = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Role).Value;
```

so i change how claims syntax was written to include the claimtype

```
 new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role.ToString()),
```